# Compare multiple string columns return different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with four string columns

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
A.    A.   A.    B. 
A.    A.   A.    A.
A.    A.   B.    B.
```

Would like the response like this.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 Changed
A.    A.   A.    B.    B
A.    A.   A.    A.    
A.    A.   B.    B.    B
```

```
lst = col1,col2,col3,col4
def compare(**kwargs):
  if all(col1 for i in my_list):
     return col1
  elif all(col2 for i in my_list):
     return col2
  elif all(col3 for i in (col3,col4):
     return col3
  elif col4 == col4 :
     return col2
  

df['changed'] = df.apply(lambda x: compare(x), axis = 1)
```

Bit stuck in getting this right if anyone can help?

Comment: Does it possible to have 'A. A. B. C.' or 'A. A. B. A.'?

Comment: Yes its possible but very unlikely

Comment: For the 2 cases, what is the expected output for `Changed` column?

Comment: It would be the latest change

Comment: So for the first case 'C' and the second case 'A', right?

Comment: yes exactly C and A

Answer (score 1):

Take the last column if not all values are identical:

```
df['Changed'] = df['col4'].mask(df.eq(df['col1'], axis=0).all(1), '')
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 Changed
0   A.   A.   A.   B.      B.
1   A.   A.   A.   A.
2   A.   A.   B.   B.      B.
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T, I just realized it ;)

Comment: This issue with this it doesn't show NAN when they are the same

Comment: @David yes it does, remove the `''` in the `where`.

Comment: Hmm thanks but for some reason thats not working

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact expected output? How is it not working? Do you use a different dataset?

Comment: @DavidDraper. I tested the answer and it worked for me.

Comment: I think the issue is there is an additional column at the start with a name.

Comment: Can you provide the real example? This is easy to fix, you just need to use only the relevant columns: `df.eq(…)` -> `df[your_cols].eq(…)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `mask` to select row where there are some changes. I slightly modify your dataframe to take into account special cases.

```
mask = df.ne(df.shift(fill_value=df['col1'], axis=1))
df['Changed'] = df.mask(mask.sum(1) <= 0)[mask].ffill(axis=1)['col4']
```

```
>>> df
  col1 col2 col3 col4 Changed
0   A.   A.   A.   B.      B.
1   A.   A.   A.   A.     NaN
2   A.   A.   B.   B.      B.
3   A.   A.   B.   C.      C.
4   A.   A.   B.   A.      A.
```

Comment: @DavidDraper. Can you give it a try to my answer, please? Does it work?